# jquery next() function not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent

I want to add the toggle to my looped div class. But it is not working.
This is my Html Code.

`

```
<div class="bookNowBtn selectCar" id="vechile_toggle">
     <div class="vechile_toggleCls">
         Select
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="vechile_roomCls" id="vechile_room">
             <form>
                 //something goes here
             </form>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

`
This is my jquery COde.

`

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".vechile_toggleCls").click(function(){
             //alert('hello');
             $(this).parent().next().next().next(".vechile_roomCls").slideToggle();
         });
     });
 </script>
```

`

why is my code not working

Comment: you can use div id instead it as you have give id="vechile_room"
as $("#vechile_room").slideToggle();

Comment: Id only toggle the first div in looped statement. So, i used class

Answer (score 2):

`.next()` is used to target next sibling element.You need to use `.find()` instead:

```
 $(".vechile_toggleCls").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().next().find(".vechile_roomCls").slideToggle();
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6mjcuv7f/)**

Comment: Thanks Milind Anantwar, This code also worked perfect for me

Comment: @vijayrana: glad it helps

Answer (score 1):

The element you are looking for is the descendant of the next sibling of the clicked element so

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".vechile_toggleCls").click(function() {
     //alert('hello');
     $(this).parent().next().find(".vechile_roomCls").stop().slideToggle();
   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bookNowBtn selectCar" id="vechile_toggle">
  <div class="vechile_toggleCls">
    Select
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="vechile_roomCls" id="vechile_room">
      <form>
        //something goes here
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```